# Check charecter length of each p tag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<p class="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="mytext">Lo ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="mytext">Lorem</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".mytext").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).text().length;
    //alert(n)
    if (n > 5) {
        alert(n + " more than 5");
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

I am trying to find character length for each `p` for doing some condition. can anyone pls help? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/id10922606/dv8f6p5e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    $(".mytext").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length;/* use this to remove all space*/
   var n = $.trim($(this).text()).length;/* use this to remove end spaces*/
        alert(n)
    if (n > 5){
          alert(n + " more than 5");
            $(this).css("color" , "red");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rather use `.filter()` function:

```
$(".mytext").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().length > 5;
}).css("color" , "red")
```

Comment: how to add conditions like length > 26 & < 36 add class oneline,
length  > 36 add class twoline for above code?

Comment: By using `return $(this).text().length > 26 && $(this).text().length < 36;`